# Why the result of "SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;" is 1?

Tags: mysql

I am a Chinese. I can not understand why the result of "SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci", which is the example on [MySQL document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), is 1?

Besides, I have read [another article](http://stackz.ru/en/543580/equals-vs-like). It set the charset as latin1 first, and then the result of "SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci" becomes 0. Why is the two results of the same sql is different? Is it because the charset difference?

On [MySQL document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

```
mysql> SELECT 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
+-----------------------------------------+
| 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       0 |
+-----------------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
+--------------------------------------+
| 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    1 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

On the [another article](http://stackz.ru/en/543580/equals-vs-like).

```
mysql> set charset latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
+---------------------------------------+
| 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci  |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
+------------------------------------------+
| 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci  |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                        0 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```